# I need to change my MVC2 home page to a different page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can one go about doing that.  I am betting it has something to do with the routing engine.  Not sure though.  I will continue to browse the interwebs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, you will want to change your default route. It is in the Global.asax.cs file (by default).

The default one looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

This line:

```
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Is the defaults. The default controller name is `Home` and the default action is `Index`. Change them to what you desire.

You can learn more about routing [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/routing).

Answer (score 0):

Look at your default route.  Out of the box, it will point to the index method of the home controller.